# Unable to display result

Tags: c

I am wondering what is wrong with my code. I was unable to print out the grade when the user entered the marks. Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int x,y,z;
    printf("Enter mark for Bahasa:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter mark for english:");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Enter mark for Math:");
    scanf("%d", &z);

    if((x > 75) && ( y > 80) && (z > 60))
        printf(" Grade A");
    else if (( x > 75) && ( y < 80) && (z < 60))
        printf ("Grade B");
    else
        printf("honor");         
}
```

Comment: _nothing_ is printed, or do you see "honor" printed?

Comment: What marks are you typing in to test it? Are you using decimals?

Comment: Please add to your question: Your inputs, the program's output, your expected output.

Comment: It works. Maybe the if condition is not right, so the result is not what you want.

Comment: This is a weird way to come up with a grade. I would also add a space after you prompt the user for console readability.

Comment: Can you also mention the platform and the compiler details?

Comment: There's nothing that wrong. There might be a logical mistake or you might be running a different executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have a gap. a state that is not covered in the if conditions. What if the user entered exactly 75, 80 and 60? If I were you I'd use ">=" instead of ">" and "<=" instead of "<". also if x is < 75 is not covered at all.

You might try to put this statement before the "if" conditions to see what is it exactly you are getting from `scanf()`.

```
printf("My inputs are %d, %d and %d\n",x ,y ,z);
```

Once you are sure of your inputs. Then check your conditions. I think there might be a problem with that line (as mentioned earlier x<75 is not covered at all) :

```
else if (( x > 75) && ( y < 80) && (z < 60));
```

Maybe what you really need is

```
(x<=75)
```

Either way, an example run of your program will be helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add end-of-lines to your `printf`.  Like so:

```
printf("honor\n");
```

Your shell prompt might overwrite the output if you work in command line.